# How to query on a specific element in a hash

Tags: arrays, mongodb, hash

I have a document in collection like:

// Document One

{

```
"_id" : ObjectId("556411af7361123456"),
"owner_name": "emma",
"animal_weight" : [
    {
        "pet" : dog,
        "weight" : 112
    },
    {
        "pet" : cat,
        "weight" : 30
    }
]
```

}

{

```
"_id" : ObjectId("556411af736112345678910"),
"owner_name": "jenny",
"animal_weight" : [
    {
        "pet" : dog,
        "weight" : 100
    },
    {
        "pet" : animal,
        "weight" : 25
    }
]
```

}

I want the mongodb to return the name of the owner (owner_name) whose dog's weight is over 110. what should the query be like? Basically, there are two elements in the array 'animal_weight', each element (hash) includes two key-value pairs (one is pet type, either dog or cat; the other is the weight of the pet). How to apply a filter in the mongo query on dog's weight? Thanks!

Comment: In what language?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify that, in mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the $elemMatch operator for your query:

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

The query might be something like:

```
db.pets.find({ "animal_weight": { $elemMatch: { pet: "dog", weight: {$gt: 110} } } }, {_id:0, owner_name:1})
```